# Do something before consuming stream, using highland.js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactive-programming, highland.js

I'm trying to code a writable stream which takes a stream of objects and inputs them into a mongodb database. Before consuming the stream of objects, I first need to wait for the db-connection to establish, but I seem to be doing something wrong, because the program never gets to the insertion-part.

```es2015
// ./mongowriter.js

let mongo = mongodb.MongoClient,
    connectToDb = _.wrapCallback(mongo.connect);

export default url => _.pipeline(s => {
  return connectToDb(url).flatMap(db => {
    console.log('Connection established!');
    return s.flatMap(x => /* insert x into db */);
  });
});

....

// Usage in other file
import mongowriter from './mongowriter.js';

let objStream = _([/* json objects */]);

objStream.pipe(mongoWriter);
```

The program just quits without "Connection established!" ever being written to the console.

**What am I missing? Is there some kind of idiom I should be following?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading the source and some general experimentation, I figured out how to do a single asynchronous thing and then continue processing through the stream. Basically, you **use flatMap to replace the event from the asynchronous task with the stream you actually want to process.**

Another quirk I didn't expect and which was throwing me off, was that `_.pipeline` won't work unless the original stream is fully consumed in the callback. That's why it won't work simply putting in a _.map and log stuff (which was how I tried to debug it). Instead one needs to make sure to have an `each` or `done` at the end. Below is a minimal example:

```
export default _ => _.pipeline( stream => {
  return _(promiseReturningFunction())
    .tap(_ => process.stdout.write('.'))
    .flatMap(_ => stream)
    .each(_ => process.stdout.write('-'));
});

// Will produce something like the following when called with a non-empty stream.
// Note the lone '.' in the beginning.
// => .-------------------
```

Basically, a '.' is output when the async function is done, and a '-' for every object of the stream.

Hopefully, this saves someone some time. Took embarrassingly long for me to figure this out. ^^